# Using Lagrange Multipliers to find minimum value of 3 variable equation

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Is possible to find minimum values of $f(x) = 7x +5y + 10z $  subject to the constraint $3x + y + 2z \geq 3$ and $-x + 2y + 4z \geq 5 $ ? I tried, and I get value of $\lambda $, but I think I made a mistake in the development.

Comment: Please add more details about what you tried and obtained, and also why you think there is a mistake. It will surely help a lot potential answerers.

Comment: I tried this: $$\nabla  f(x) = \lambda  \nabla g(x) + \mu \nabla h(x)$$ $$(7,5,10) = \lambda (3, 1, 2) + \mu (-1, 2, 4)$$ And I get $$\lambda = \frac{19}{7}, \ \ \mu = \frac{8}{7} $$ After this, i don't know how to proceed. In the system of equations, I get that: $$\begin {cases} 7 = 3 \lambda - \mu \\ 5 = \lambda + 2 \mu \\ 10 = 2 \lambda + 4 \mu \\ 3x+y+2z = 3 \\ −x+2y+4z = 5   \end {cases}$$ I guess I need to add & f(x) & in system, but, I tried and got stuck.

Comment: Are you required to use a Lagrangian to solve it? Because you might be able to do it  using the Simplex Algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feasible domain of this problem is an infinite wedge, bounded by two halfplanes. The edge of this wedge is parallel to $(3,1,2)\times(-1,2,4)$, i.e. parallel to $v:=(0,-2,1)$. Since $\nabla f\cdot v=0$ the objective function $f$ is constant along this wedge, and this makes the problem somewhat degenerate.

Inspection of the given data suggests to introduce the new variable $t:=y+2z$. In this way the dimension of the problem is reduced: Instead of $f(x,y,z)=7x+5(y+2z)$ we have to minimize the function $g(x,t):=7x+5t$ under the constraints
$$3x+t\geq3,\qquad-x+2t\geq5\ ,$$
or
$$3x+t=3+u,\qquad -x+2t=5+v\tag{1}$$
with "new coordinates"  $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$. Solving $(1)$ for $x$ and $t$ we obtain
$$x={1\over7}(1+2u-v)\qquad t={1\over7}(18+u+3v)\ ,$$
which leads to
$$\hat g(u,v)=g\bigl(x(u,v),t(u,v)\bigr)={1\over7}(97+29u+8v)\ .$$
As $u$ and $v$ have to be nonnegative the minimal possible value of $\hat g$, hence of the original $f$, is $${97\over7}\ .$$

Comment: This idea is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The lagrangian method of multipliers should be done with equality restrictions so introducing two slack variables $\epsilon_i$ we have the lagrangian formulation

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2) = 7x+5y+10 z +\lambda_1(3x+y+2z-3-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_2(-x+2y+4z-5-\epsilon_2^2)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 =\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 3 \lambda_1 -\lambda_2 +7 \\
 \lambda_1 +2 \lambda_2 +5 \\
 2 \lambda_1 +4 \lambda_2 +10 \\
 2 \epsilon_1 \lambda_1  \\
 2 \epsilon_2 \lambda_2  \\
 3 x+y+2 z-3 -\epsilon_1^2\\
 -x+2 y+4 z-5-\epsilon_2^2 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving this system we obtain the solution

$$
x = \frac 17, y = \mu, z = \frac{1}{14}(18-7\mu), \lambda_1 = -\frac{19}{7}, \lambda_2 = -\frac 87, \epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2 = 0
$$

for $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ giving $\frac{97}{7}$ as the minimum value.

From $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2 = 0$ we conclude that the two restrictions are actuating. Follows a graphic showing in blue a piece of the feasible region and in orange the plane $7x+5y+10z-15=0$

[image]

Comment: How you get $y = \mu$?

Comment: @DarthVictor $\mu$ is a parameter indicating that the solution set is the line $$(x,y,z) = \left(\frac 17, \mu,\frac{1}{14}(18-7\mu)\right)$$ for $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: But the value of $\mu$ is equal to $\lambda_2$? I put the value $-\frac{8}{7}$ and get the minimum value. Am I wrong?

Comment: The minimum is attained all along the line that can be depicted (in red)  in the attached graphics. $\mu$ is not a multiplier. Is it a free parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I made confusion, because I used $\mu $ as multiplier

Answer (score 0):

The primal:
$$f(x,y,z)=7x +5y + 10z \ \to \text{min} \\
\ \ \ \ 3x + y + 2z \geq 3\\
-x + 2y + 4z \geq 5$$
The dual:
$$g(a,b)=3a+5b \ \to \text{max} \\
3a-b \leq 7\\
a + 2b \leq 5\\
2a+4b\le 10$$
Maximum occurs at the corner point of the [open feasible region](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pdjjzjxuvt):
$$g\left(\frac{19}{7},\frac87\right)=\frac{97}{7}.$$
Hence, the minimum of $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is $\frac{97}{7}$.

Can you find the critical point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ from the dual theorem?

Comment: I tried to use the dual theorem, but... I could not

Comment: Dual theorem states the min of primal is equal to max of dual, hence the final answer is 97/7. In fact, no need to find x,y and z. Good luck.